# How I can set PowerBi dataset refresh for every 15mins

Tags: powerbi, servicenow

Connected Servicenow to PowerBi via Rest API call, If any new record/request created in the servicenow, the dataset should also get refresh in powerbi. Is there any approach where I can set my dataset to refresh for every 15minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Power Automate Flow with a time-based trigger (similar to a CRON job) to refresh your dataset every 15 minutes.

It is straightforward to set up, like this:

[image]

Comment: 1. Do you have any doc for the reference
2. Does it have any limitation for refresh

Comment: 1. Not really - perhaps Power Automate has some documentation that is suitable. 2. We have a similar type refresh Flow in our stack (change in a table triggers refresh), and it hasn't errored. I was under the impression that the 48 times / day limitation was enforced with "any" remote trigger, so I advise you to simply check and see :-)

Comment: You will be limited to 8 refreshes per.day with pro, scheduled in PBI service or using the API. You'll need Premium to increase the number of refreshes you can do